# Importing file from another directory python

Tags: python

**Disclaimer**: I have tried adding my root of the project folder to the path and also followed [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time) but still finding issues.

My project structure is:

```
package_name
- __init__.py
folder1
    - __init__.py
    - file_to_be_tested.py
    - tests
        - __init__.py
        - test_my_test.py
```

How do I import a function from the `file_to_be_tested.py` in `test_my_test.py`? I have tried the following:

```
from package.folder1.file_to_be_tested import my_func
from folder1.file_to_be_tested import my_func
```

And for running the test file, I run the following command from the root of the package (inside `package_name`) folder:

```
python folder1/tests/test_my_test.py
```

Apologies if I didn't read enough before posting.

Comment: You forgot to add `__init__.py` file (even if it's empty) to the tests folder. 
By the way, did you add `-m` flag to the command to run the test file?

Comment: Sorry I added that too, all my `__init__.py` files are empty. Still the same error.

Comment: If I add the `-m`, I get the following error:

```
/Users/psr/anaconda3/bin/python: Error while finding module specification for 'folder1/tests/test_my_test.py' (ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'folder1/tests/test_my_test'). Try using 'folder1/tests/test_my_test' instead of 'folder1/tests/test_my_test.py' as the module name.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the current structure you would need to do the following:

1. In test_my_test.py, use the import:

```
from ..file_to_be_tested import my_func
```

2. Then run the test script as a module

```
python -m folder1.tests.test_my_test
```

---

As an alternative to running the test script as a module (using the -m option),  you can do the following steps to import the tests as part of the package and run them from another script.

A) in test_my_test.py, put the tests you want to run into a function, such as `run_tests()`

B) Add an `__init__.py` file to the tests directory with `from .test_my_test import run_tests`

C) Create a script outside of the `package_name` directory, which will import and run the tests as:

```
import package_name.folder1.tests as tests

tests.test_my_test.run_tests()
```

Comment: I tried the first part and it worked. Will try the second later. Thank you!